# how to use UIToolbar above UICollectionViewController?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

today I am learning how to use UICollectioViewController, but I have a problem. I wanna add a toolbar above a UICollectionViewController, but I dont know what to do. Dragging a UIToolbar into storyboard just make UICollectionViewCell dissappear. I wanna make something like in this pic : [image]

is there somebody can help me? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is, if you drag a collection view controller in the storyboard, that's all it is, a collection view controller. If you inspect on the left part, you'll notice that it does not even have a generic UIView at the top of its view's hierarchy, but a UICollectionView.

If you want a view controller with more than just that, you'll have to use a generic UIViewController in the storyboard, and then drag onto it a UICollectionView and a UIToolBar.

The screenshot below shows the two different cases:

[image]